# Sencha Touch first run Messagebox Error

Tags: android, eclipse, sencha-touch

I've just installed Sencha on Eclipse and build hello world app,
The is RUNNING OK, but the Message boxes don't work:

```
Ext.setup({
    onReady: function() {
       if (Ext.is.Android) 
      Ext.Msg.alert("INFO", "Welcome Android user!");   
       if (Ext.is.Blackberry)
      Ext.Msg.alert("INFO", "Welcome Blackberry user!");
         if (Ext.is.iPad)
        Ext.Msg.alert("INFO", "Welcome iPad user!");
       }
     });
```

The Error that I get in the eclipse log:

> E/Web Console(279): Error: [ERROR][Anonymous] Using Ext.Msg without requiring Ext.MessageBox at file:///android_asset/www/senchatouch/src/log/writer/Console.js?_dc=1342002536493:17

I can't figure what is wrong,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the Ext.MessageBox component.  Also I would do the setup in an Ext.application declaration instead of Ext.setup.  Additionally your OS check should be Ext.os.is not Ext.is  I put together a SenchaFiddle for you.  Take a look here:

http://www.senchafiddle.com/#NKlNS

Hope that helps